# Xamarin.iOS Operation is not supported on this platform Exception at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, json.net

I'm working on a cross-platform project with Xamarin.Forms. In my project, I'm using an API to login by a username and password. When I try to login on Android and UWP platorms, it works perfectly. But when I want to login in my iOS project, It throws an exception that says:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on
>   this platform.

The Exception is thrown on this line of my code:

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("token", content);
```

Here is the full StackTrace:

> at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor (System.String name,
>   System.Type returnType, System.Type[] parameterTypes, System.Type
>   owner, System.Boolean skipVisibility) [0x00006] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/DynamicMethod.notsupported.cs:62
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod
>   (System.String name, System.Type returnType, System.Type[]
>   parameterTypes, System.Type owner) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.cs:45
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDefaultConstructor[T]
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.cs:244
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator
>   (System.Type createdType) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs:780
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x0008b] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs:813
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x00007] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs:340
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x0010f] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs:1249
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd
>   (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00034] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs:1003
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[TKey,TValue].Get (TKey
>   key) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs:64
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract
>   (System.Type type) [0x0000b] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs:198
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe
>   (System.Type type) [0x0000b] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:133
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x0000e] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:143
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00046]
>   in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:907
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
>   reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:886
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value,
>   System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   [0x0002d] in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:830
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in
>   /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:786
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
>   [0x00000] in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:719
>
> at
>   Restaurant.Core.DataServices.LoginDataService+d__0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00222] in
>   C:\Projects\Restaurant\Restaurant\Restaurant.Core\DataServices\LoginDataService.cs:44
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at
>   Restaurant.Core.ViewModels.Login.LoginViewModel+<b__13_0>d.MoveNext
>   () [0x00058] in
>   C:\Projects\Restaurant\Restaurant\Restaurant.Core\ViewModels\Login\LoginViewModel.cs:78
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at
>   Restaurant.Core.Helpers.ExceptionHandler+d__3.MoveNext
>   () [0x000f6] in
>   C:\Projects\Restaurant\Restaurant\Restaurant.Core\Helpers\ExceptionHandler.cs:38

I Googled it and finally found that Xamarin.iOS has [some limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#no-dynamic-code-generation). The System.Reflection.Emit is not available in Xamarin.iOS.

I guess something is wrong with Newtonsoft.Json or maybe with Xamarin itself, But I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to resolve the problem:

1. Find what exactly line is causing the problem and try to find something alternative that works for you
2. Try to install some older (or newer if available) version of NewtonSoft Json and see if it works
3. Submit the issue to NewtonSoft and wait till/if they handle it: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues

You may also submit the issue to Xamarin, but obviously it is their current technical decision to make it like this, so you can't expect they'll take it as urgent or that they are even willing to fix it.