# PlatformNotSupportedException on iOS using Entity Framework Core and Xamarin Forms

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with SQLite for the first time on Xamarin Forms.

TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, I noticed the following exception, each time I do an operation on EF on the iOS Platform.

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor (System.String name, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes attributes, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callingConvention, System.Type returnType, System.Type[] parameterTypes, System.Type owner, System.Boolean skipVisibility) [0x00006] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/DynamicMethod.notsupported.cs:74
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ILEmitResolverBuilder.BuildTypeNoCache (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00038] in <29788903d3cf48c4a1368d8b368c6521>:0
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ILEmitResolverBuilder.<.ctor>b__12_0 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCacheKey key, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite cs) [0x00000] in <29788903d3cf48c4a1368d8b368c6521>:0
at (wrapper delegate-invoke)

On the Android, it is working fine, But on the iOS I am getting above exception. I am using latest version of Xamarin.forms and EntityFramework.Sqlite packages. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691293/xamarin-ios-operation-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-exception-at-newtonsoft

Comment: I checked the above link but it is not the same case

Comment: @Akanksha It would be best if you could post the code snippet for the EF operation. It would help us all in understanding a bit more about the issue if we know the scenario where this is happening.

Comment: @Akanksha A few of my models use "NotMapped". Do any of your models?

Comment: Yes, Many of the models use "NotMapped"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the main application project

--nolinkaway --linkskip=mscorlib under "Project Options -> iOS Build -> Additional mtouch arguments

You could also try disabling the AOT, By enabling the interpreter, i.e; add --interpreter to your mtouch args.

Comment: Same results after trying the --nolinkaway --linkskip=mscorlib under "Project Options -> iOS Build -> Additional mtouch arguments

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Using iOS 13.6, Xamarin Forms 4.7.0.1239, EF Core Sqlite 3.1.6